# New Request for forecasting fields

Tags: reporting, forecast

There’s a request to change our global process of how we forecast (sales manager/business unit manager commits) in SFDC.  Below are notes from my meeting and what the request consisted of. Changing the standard close date field to be used by only the BUMs(business unit managers) and have that field drive the pipeline and forecast date and having the sales reps use a new close date field is going to cause big issues, mainly because that’s a standard field that you can’t change or hide and its used by reports and many different areas of SF (related lists, views, campaigns, EVERYTHING, etc.)

I need help to provide some other possible options for what they are trying to do. I don’t want to make this over complicated for the user, changes to be made to the system, or over-developed.

Here are some things I've thought up so far:

- Update the Sales Manager/BUM Commit field so it is just Sales
  Manager Commit
- Add a new Sales Manager Commit Close Date
- Add a BUM Commit checkbox
- Change the current Close Date field to be the
  BUM Commit Close Date - This will determine where the opportunity
  actually is in the pipeline and forecast
- Create a new Close Date
  field for sales reps
- Create a workflow that fills in the SM Close
  Date based on the SR Close Date and the BUM Close Date based on the
  SM Close Date
- Don't allow for the lower level roles to see the
  manager above them's changes
- Create a Forcasting object for
  managers to report on.

Has any one had to deal with this or have better options that won't effect the whole reporting/forecasting process? Any help and opinions will help tremendously! If you need clarification just let me know what I need to clarify as this is pretty specific to our org.

Comment: this is a pretty broad question with many possible answers. I'm presuming that you are using the Opportunity for forecasting.  (1) Look at the OOB forecast feature. It is intended to allow for managers to apply judgments versus rolled up Oppo numbers/dates (2) Leave the OOB CloseDate field alone -- many troubles will ensue if it is redefined -- sb the most likely date for opportunity to close ; all other dates should be custom fields.